# Proper way to reference a form with AngularJS while conforming to XHTML 1.1 standards?

Tags: angularjs, forms, xhtml

.NET is removing the `name` attribute from the `form` element I've defined in my master page:

```
<form
   name="aspnetForm"
   runat="server"
   onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}"
   ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur','debounce':{'default':250,'blur':0}}">
```

which gets rendered as:

```
<form
   method="post"
   action="...the current url..."
   onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
   id="aspnetForm"
   ng-model-options="{updateOn:'default blur','debounce':{'default':250,'blur':0}}"
   class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-date"> == $0
```

From [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10) and [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc57y7e.aspx), it seems that the `name` attribute is formally depreciated in XHTML 1.0 and not allowed in 1.1, and we should use the `id` attribute instead. However, [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) uses the `name` attribute to publish the form on the current scope. I want to check the validity of the form using AngularJS with `ng-disabled="!aspnetForm.$valid"` but don't see how to make `$scope` aware of the form. I've tried a few variations of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23272092/2596509) suggested code in my controller without success. I've also tried [setting the clientidmode to static](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287448/2596509) but that doesn't seem to affect the `name` tag.

Comment: I remember developing Webs with XHTML 1.1 **nine years ago**. However, in the AngularJS documentation its refers to use with HTML5. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00

Answer (score 1):

The scope name of the form can also be set using the attribute `ng-form='aspnetForm'`. You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.4/src/ng/directive/form.js#L72) for where it sets the name.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error because I have `<form... ng-form='aspnetForm'></form>`, which has this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20893935/2596509. Thoughts?

Comment: Any reason using a div like the answer mentions wouldn't work?

Comment: I need the `<form>` submit functionality.

Comment: And if I do a `<div>` I get a whole bunch of errors, currently "control ... of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag". I'm going to unaccept your answer temporarily until we can figure out how to get Angular recognizing my form tag.

Comment: Then you might be at a point where you need to throw something out. You could use Angular's form submit option instead or use HTML5 instead of XHTML 1.1 or use .NET form validation instead of Angular. As for the actual question of how to get the form on the scope, this answer is correct and unfortunately is the only other option I can see that will do this for you.

Comment: Matthew, I appreciate your help, but I don't agree that this is a correct answer to my question. If a XHTML 1.1 compliant form element cannot be referenced by Angular then I think this question should remain unanswered.